# what is this error for reshaping in python?

Tags: python, list, reshape, tensor

I have act[‘a’] of torch.Size([1, 64, 32, 32]) and act[‘b’] of torch.Size([1, 128, 16, 16]) and act[‘c’] of torch.Size([1, 256, 8, 8]).
and I have:

```
target = {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}
for i in range(800):
                target['a'].append(act['a'])
                target['b'].append(act['b'])
                target['c'].append(act['c'])
```

so now the size of target[‘a’] is [800, 1, 64, 32, 32]. how can I reshape it to [1, 64, 800, 32, 32]?

I tried

```
tf.reshape(target['a'], [1, 64, 800,32,32])
```

and it gives me this error that I took a screenshot of:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you expect?

```
a = tf.zeros([1, 64, 32, 32])
target = {'a': [a] * 800}
m = tf.convert_to_tensor(target['a'])
n = tf.reshape(m, [1, 64, 800, 32, 32])
```

```
>>> m.shape
TensorShape([800, 1, 64, 32, 32])

>>> n.shape
TensorShape([1, 64, 800, 32, 32])
```

Comment: I wrote: target.reshape([3, 1, 64, 800, 32, 32]) and it gives me this error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'reshape'. as you can see with my code target is a dict

Comment: Forget what I wrote earlier, I didn't understand

Comment: target['a'] is a list. how can i reshape it?

Comment: @Ghost. I updated my answer. I think I should work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your time